# "Give seminars" or "lead seminars"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Currently, I am finishing my statement of purpose, which I need to write in order to apply to graduate programs. In my statement, I want to describe my teaching experience (for a semester, I taught a course in Mathematics for undergraduate students; the classes had a form of seminars). However, I don't want to use a word "teach", because it is used many times in the very same paragraph. I found two possible options. The first is to say:

> For a semester, I **gave seminars** in Mathematics.

The other possible option is suggested by my friend, who studies in the US:

> For a semester, I **led seminars** in Mathematics.

However, neither of these options sound right - according to Google, they are not actively used.

I would like to wonder, what is the common way to describe teaching experience in this case? How to formulate the sentence I mentioned *without* using the word "taught"?

Comment: "I delivered seminars" is more formal than "I gave seminars" and is a suitable (though less widely used) alternative to "I taught seminars."

Comment: Were the seminars "taught" (most of the time you provided information to the participants), or was it a more open, discussion-type arrangement? If the latter, "led" or "facilitated" might be better choices. "Delivered" is a good choice as @Chemomechanics says - it's neutral in this respect.

Comment: @ArchContrarian, in this sense, these seminars were "taught" - most of the time I was delivering the material. Yet, any discussions in the process were welcomed. I suppose the best solution would be to use "delivered seminars". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Held** seminars](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22held+seminars%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=yFAcWrXUA6_P8AfvyK7wAQ)

and

[**Conducted** seminars](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22conducted+seminars%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=-lEcWuCHHbLP8Afp4bpQ)

are often used, and have [higher ngram scores](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=held+seminars%2Cgave+seminars%2C+conducted+seminars%2C+led+seminars&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheld%20seminars%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgave%20seminars%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconducted%20seminars%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cled%20seminars%3B%2Cc0) than *led* or *gave* seminars, although two of the examples provided by the [Cambridge online definition of *Seminar*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22conducted+seminars%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=-lEcWuCHHbLP8Afp4bpQ) both use **give**.

So it would appear perfectly acceptable to stick with ‘gave’, but if you wish to emphasize the involvement of others you might prefer ‘conducted’, which has a more sophisticated ring.